# Information about embedded software test tools

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests

I am looking for a software test tool solution to automate Unit / Module / Integration Testing of Embedded Software (C, C++, Java).
Does somebody have an idea about it? It will be nice if it’s open source.

Answer (score 1):

You'll typically want a unit testing framework for each.
There are open source frameworks for C ([Cunit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cunit/)), C++ ([CppUnit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/)) and Java ([JUnit](http://www.junit.org/)).
You can easily find others.

You should also consider test coverage tools, to tell you
what part of your code the unit tests don't cover.   You'll likely need of of these for each of the 3 languages, too.

If you a set of test coverage tools that all have the same style (and thus learning curve), and whose output can be combined to provide test coverage for an application coded in all 3 lanuages, you can consider using my company's (Semantic Designs) [test coverage tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage).  Idon't know of a another set of test coverage tools that can combine test coverage data from all 3 languages to provided a unified result.